# Warum heißt es »Folgende Dinge tun etw.« aber »Die folgenden Dinge tun etw.«?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending

Warum heißt es

> Die folgenden Präsentationen finden statt.
>
> Folgenden Präsentationen bleibe ich fern

aber

> Folgende Präsentationen finden statt.

Als Muttersprachler weiß ich, dass es so heißen muss, aber grammatikalisch kann ich es nicht begründen. Warum wird das Adjektiv *folgende* im dritten Beispiel nicht an den Numerus des von ihm beschriebenen Substantivs angepasst?

Comment: Aber es *ist* an den Numerus angepaßt. Der Plural von "folgender/folgende/folgendes" ist nunmal "folgende". Die Frage in der Überschrift ist viel interessanter.

Comment: Argh, das stimmt natürlich. Danke. Aber warum heißt es dann *die folgenden*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich glaube, hier liegt ein Missverständnis vor.

> Warum wird das Adjektiv folgende im dritten Beispiel nicht an den Numerus des von ihm beschriebenen Substantivs angepasst?

Im dritten Satz ist *folgende Präsentationen* das **Subjekt** des Satzes. Deshalb muss es im **Nominativ** verwendet werden; im zweiten Satz ist *folgenden Präsentationen* das Objekt des Satzes und muss somit im Dativ geschrieben werden.

**EDIT:**

Ich glaube, die Frage jetzt richtig verstanden zu haben. Es geht um die Endung von *folgend* je nachdem, ob das Wort mit oder ohne Artikel verwendet wird.

Dazu gibt es im Deutschen folgende Regel:

Adjektive werden [stark dekliniert](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Starke_Deklination_der_Adjektive), wenn sie ohne Artikel und [schwach dekliniert](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Schwache_Deklination_der_Adjektive), wenn sie mit Artikel stehen.

**Pluraldeklination**

```
Kasus         stark       schwach
----------------------------------------------
Nominativ     folgende    (die) folgenden
Genitiv       folgender   (der) folgenden
Dativ         folgenden   (den) folgenden
Akkusativ     folgende    (die) folgenden
```

Comment: Im zweiten Beispiel ist es mir klar. Aber wo ist der Unterschied zwischen dem ersten und dem dritten Beispiel?

Comment: Genau, das war meine Frage, vielleicht nicht ganz eindeutig formuliert. Vielen Dank für die Antwort!

Comment: Danke auch! Hat mir die Gelegenheit gegeben, meiner *Schwäche* für Tabellen zu frönen. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... ich denke, dass es sich sowohl beim ersten wie auch beim dritten Beispiel um den Nominativ handelt:

Wer oder was findet statt? -- "Die folgenden Präsentationen" bzw. "Folgende Präsentationen".

Der Unterschied liegt vrmtl. eher darin, dass es sich im ersten Fall wirklich um ein Adjektiv handelt und damit im Nominativ Plural vorliegt, während im dritten Beispiel das Wort "folgende" wie eine (modale? temporale?) Präposition gebraucht wird.

Was sagen die Grammatik-Gurus dazu?

EDIT:

Mit dem Update von splattne (s. o.) möchte ich meine Antwort zurückziehen... ;-)